# How to write OR condition in .find methode

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

Here im filtering Rec from an Array for single object its working well but i wana 2 its filter on multiple  Records

```
someval(value){
  if(value.length>4){
   this._pagedItems= this.allItems.find(e => e.uniqueid=value.toUpperCase() || e => e.uniqueid=value.toUpperCase() );
```

Here im getting Error at ||

Answer (score 0):

```
someval(value){
  if(value.length>4){
   this._pagedItems= this.allItems.find(e => e.uniqueid == value.toUpperCase() || e.uniqueid == value.toUpperCase() );
```

You should not use `e =>` in or expression again.

Comment: Its not Filtering My Rec\

Comment: Shouldn't this be `e.uniqueid === value.toUpperCase()`?